# How to adjust cell size in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to design a tableView like this

[image]

But when I adjust

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I put `cell.contentView.frame.width = CGFloat(tableView.bounds.width - 40)` to make the contentView of Cell smaller, but it shows error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'width' is a get-only property

So how to make the cell smaller.

Any helps would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why don't you put a leading space ?

Comment: I found the problem, if I want to design like this, I have to put an UIView inside the contentView of the cell. :)

Comment: exactly and then put a leading space or any other construct to that new view

Comment: Yes, look at my answer.

Comment: Yeah that's it. Also consider thinking about UIStackView if it makes sense for your UIDesign, happy coding

Comment: Thanks man, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly assign to the `width` of a `CGRect`. A `CGRect` consists of `position` and `size`, and the `size` in turn consists of `height` and `width`.

In other words, `frame.width` is just a getter for `frame.size.width`

So the correct assignment would be:

`cell.contentView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(tableView.bounds.width - 40)`

But this altogether is a bad pattern. 
You should design the cell as a custom cell, either in a new .xib file or as a prototype cell in the storyboard, and use AutoLayout to layout the subviews of the cell's contentView.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return calculatedHeightForSpecificIndexPath
}
```

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang glad I could help. If my answer did help you, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: wish I could, @Khuong asked the question thou. Hope he'll remember the question now

Answer (score 0):

To custom a cell like that image I posted, just create an UIView inside the contentView of cell, like this:

[image]

The result here:

[image]

Comment: I didn't see any different of those cells

Comment: I just give an example :)